# Tkinter prints None :(

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and wanna make a funny project but idk why it kept print none pls help.

```
import tkinter as tk
# from tkinter import ttk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

def age():
    age_input= print('Your age is :'), entryint.get()
    output_string.set(age_input)






# window
window = ttk.Window(themename= 'journal')
window.title('SUPER SMART AGE CALCULATOR')
window.geometry('690x420')

#title
title_labor = ttk.Label(master = window,
                        text = 'pls enter your age',
                          font= 'Calibri 20 bold')
title_labor.pack()

#input field
imput_frame = ttk.Frame(master=window)
entryint = tk.IntVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(master = imput_frame,
                   textvariable=entryint)
button = ttk.Button(master = imput_frame,
                    text = 'Cal',
                    command= age)
entry.pack(side='left',
           padx= 10)
button.pack(side='left')
imput_frame.pack(pady= 10)

#output
output_string = tk.StringVar()
output_lable= ttk.Label(master=window,
                        text='output',
                         font= 'Calibri 20 ',
                         textvariable=output_string)
output_lable.pack(pady=5)


#run
window.mainloop()
```

i tried
age_input= ' your age is ' , entryint.get()
output_string.set(age_input)

but the result when print is : { your age is : }

Answer (score -1):

You may try the following:

```
def age():
    age_input=entryint.get()
    output_string.set(age_input)
```

Comment: Try this you get a none because you are not returning anything and your string was in the wrong place

Comment: I don't know why I am getting a negative review for this answer...If you replace the def age() with the code as I put in my answer the program runs without the NONE in the output...I dont know how to add text with code in my answer in stack overflow..but the solution I posted is correct..I tested it